# Firebase is taking too long to get data in Ionic 2 app launch on android (using firebase auth)

Tags: cordova, angular, firebase-realtime-database, ionic2, firebase-authentication

I am trying to debug my ionic 2 app. I have set authentication on. 
Once user sign in, I set a cookie and based on that cookie, I don't ask user to login again.

I am using: 
AngularFire and then making this request,
I am just making this simple query using firebase:

```
firebase.database().ref('jobs/' + this.serviceName).once('value', snap => {
  this.jobs = snap.val();
})
```

In browser on desktop it takes only: 4 seconds
but on android while debugging: 
It takes around 50 seconds to get the result. The result set has only 40 items.
I have set enable firebase logging: 
as soon as I get result I get this message: 
browser went online and then authentication key.
Once it gets result, any further request to firebase is quite fast.

The only problem I can think of could the auth token is taking too long to process.

My question is: How do i set my app so that it get token immediately and then process request.[image: after 50 seconds of app launch i get these messages in console]

Comment: What version  of Firebase are you using? There was a bug that was fixed in 3.9.0: https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/js#3.9.0

Comment: Oh yes, you are right. 
by the way sorry for late affirmation, didn't have computer for long time.